# Android Bluetooth LE SCAN_FAILED_OUT_OF_HARDWARE_RESOURCES

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

In my Android (API version 21 and above) Bluetooth LE app, the app starts by scanning for the peripheral using a `BluetoothLeScanner` and a `ScanCallback` object.

This works fine the first few times the app starts, but after starting and stopping the app a few times from Android Studio, the `onScanFailed()` callback is called with an `errorCode` of 5. This code is not even exposed by ScanCallback.java, but the sources reveal that it is declared as `public static final int SCAN_FAILED_OUT_OF_HARDWARE_RESOURCES = 5`.

When this error turns up, the only way to restore normal behaviour for the app is to turn bluetooth off and the on again.

This error code seems entirely undocumented and a rare one at that. What makes matters even more interesting is that after device discovery, the app starts scanning using another callback that listens for broadcasts from the device. This scan session will always start reliably, even after the initial discovery scan received error code 5.

The settings for the two different `ScanCallback`s differ in several ways.

**The discovery scanner is setup like this:**

```
ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
            .also {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) 
                    it.setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH)
            }
            .build()
```

And with a filter as well:
`ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(BluetoothUUID.service.parcelUuid).build()`

**Meanwhile, the broadcast listening scanner is setup like this:**

```
ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .build()
```

The filter for the broadcast scanner is empty.

*How do I avoid putting the BLE subsystem in this state, and why does this even occur?*

Comment: Make sure you are doing Gatt.disconnect and gatt.close after you disconnect ble

Comment: I do that; `disconnect()` when business is finished and `close()` after receiving `STATE_DISCONNECTED` in `BluetoothGattCallback`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to getting rid of this is not to use `ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH`. This being Android, with its wealth of different devices, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

configure like this:

```
      new ScanSettings.Builder ()
                     .setScanMode (ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED)
                     .setCallbackType (ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                     .build (),...
```